# How to extract an array from a string that contains a numbered list?

Tags: php, regex, string

Using PHP, I am looking to extract an array from a string that contains a numbered list.

Example string:

```
The main points are: 1. This is point one. 2. This is point two. 3. This is point three.
```

would result in the following array:

```
[0] => 1. This is point one.
[1] => 2. This is point two.
[2] => 3. This is point three.
```

The format of the string can vary - e.g.:

```
1. This is point one, 2. This is point two, 3. This is point three.
1) This is point one  2) This is point two 3) This is point three
1 This is point one. 2 This is point two. 3 This is point three.
```

I have started using **preg_match_all** with the following pattern:

```
!((\d+)(\s+)?(\.?)(\)?)(-?)(\s+?)(\w+))!
```

but I am unsure as how to match rest of string/up to the next match.

Example available at [RegExr](http://regexr.com?32n9c)

Comment: use php's exploade function on numbers to get array

Comment: In your sample "input" you have `3. This is point 3.` and your sample "output" has `3. This is point three.`. Which one is the typo *or* is the regex/code supposed to make this correction?

Comment: Thanks - have updated the string examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your input follows your example input, as in each "point" doesn't contain a number itself, you could use the following regex:

```
\d+[^\d]*
```

In PHP, you could use `preg_match_all()` to capture everything:

```
$text = 'The main points are: 1. This is point one. 2. This is point two. 3. This is point three.';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(\d+[^\d]*)/', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

This will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. This is point one.
    [1] => 2. This is point two.
    [2] => 3. This is point three.
)
```

Again though, if there are any numbers/digits in the actual points themselves - this won't work.

If you want actual numbers to appear in each point, you'll need to define an actual "anchor" or "end" of each point, such as a period. If you can state that a `.` will appear only at the end of the point (ignoring the potential one that follows the leading-digit), you could use the following regex:

```
\d+[.)\s][^.]*\.
```

It can be dropped into the `preg_match_all()` from above just as easily:

```
preg_match_all('/(\d+[.)\s][^.]*\.)/', $text, $matches);
```

Regex explained:

```
\d+        # leading number
[.)\s]     # followed by a `.`, `)`, or whitespace
[^.]*      # any non-`.` character(s)
\.         # ending `.`
```

The caveat with the second regex is that a `.` may only appear at the end of each point (and following the leading digit). However, I think that this rule may be easier to follow than the "no numbers in the point" rule - it all depends on your actual input though.

Comment: Many thanks for a well thought out response (clear and concise).

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) ,it would be easier, just split the string based on your numbering format, and return non-empty results.
modify this to suit your needs :

http://codepad.org/tK6fGCRB

```
<?php

$theReg = '/\d\.|\d\)|\d /';
$theStrs = array(
                '1. This is point one, 2. This is point two, 3. This is point3' ,
                '1) This is point one  2) This is point two 3) This is point 3' ,
                '1 This is point one. 3 This is point three. 4 This is point 4'
                );

foreach($theStrs as $str)
   print_r(preg_split($theReg, $str , -1 , PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - I had looked at something similar, but with preg_split, the pattern/delimiter (i.e. the number in this case) is not combined with the rest of the string. If using the flag **PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE**, the number is included, but in a separate element of the array.